# Accessing VPN host by name from VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, dns

I have an Ubuntu guest running under VirtualBox on a W10 host with a VPN. I have set up both a host-only adapter and a NAT adapter as recommended in other answers here, and everything works perfectly. The only problem is from the guest I cannot access hosts on the VPN network by name (IP addresses are fine). For instance, the name `foo.bar.local` exists on the VPN network, but is not accessible from the guest (ping gives "unknown host"). Any straightforward solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the guest isn't making contact with a DNS server that's on the VPN network. Only way to fix this would be to run a DNS server inside the VPN network and then edit the guest network DNS settings to also include the IP of the DNS server. Make sure to only add this DNS server, don't make it the only one or unless you properly configure everything in the DNS server, the guest won't see the outside world.